# I am trying to split my raster list based on the tile number of MODIS in order to write a function to merge/mosaic each day

Tags: r, list, split, raster, satellite

I have been trying to split my raster list (for a month) into a list with 2 elements or two separate lists depending on extent/tile number in the MODIS name. I can't seem to get any split function to work. The files look like this: 
[List of rasters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmckz.png)

As you can see, the grid names are there in the names slot and the extents are different. Is there a way I can split them so I can write a function to go through each pair and merge/mosaic them?

Thank you

Comment: attach the code with the post. please don't post as an image

Comment: @Julia Welcome to SO. In addition to adding the minimal script, please have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that you can make a minimal reproducible example. Then it will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

With list `x`, start with

```
n <- sapply(x, names)
```

To get the names. To help you further, make a vector of a few example names, like

```
n <- c("mod10Axyz", "mod10Bxy", "mod10Aabc")
```

and edit your question.